# Building queries in steps results in duplicates, even when using Distinct()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I have a query that I am trying to build in steps, depending upon other values.  The primary query is:

```
IQueryable<Employee> query = 
    from emp in context.Employees
    where emp.PermanentClientId == Session.PermanentClientId
    orderby emp.LastName, emp.FirstName
    select emp;
```

Then, later, if a value is not null, I attempt to add it to the query with:

```
if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(divId))
   query = (from emp in query
   where emp.DivisionId == divId
   select emp).Distinct();
```

The query half-works: Only those with the correct `divId` are returned, but it returns two of each!  At first I did not use the .Distinct(), as I didn't think I would need to.  So, I added it, but it does not help - I still get two of every entity in the list (that matches the new where condition added.)

Anyone know if this is a LINQ bug or EF bug, or what the explanation/solution is?

**EDIT**

NO to all the questions about concatenating queries, etc., and the datasource will not allow duplicates, so something weird is happening in EF or LINQ to Entities.  Here is the code (more of a HACK) I used to eliminate the duplicates:

```
Employee[] empList = query.ToArray();
IDictionary<string, Employee> retval = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();

for (int i = 0; i < empList.Length; i++)
{
    Employee emp = empList[i];
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(empFilter.DivisionId) && 
        (emp.DivisionId != empFilter.DivisionId)))
            continue;

    try
    {
        string empKey = 
           emp.PermanentClientId.ToString() + '-' + emp.EmployeeId.ToString();
        retval.Add(empKey, emp);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    { }
}

return retval.Values.ToArray();
```

The dictionary won't allow duplicates on the key, which are the same columns the database does not allow duplicates on.  I hate doing this kind of stuff because of a problem with LINQ or something, but it works...

Peter

Comment: What's the schema of the Employees table?  You've confirmed that your data source doesn't already contain duplicates? When you these duplicates, are the primary keys equal?

Comment: I fail to see how you could get every entry in the list twice, given the query you've shown.  You haven't concatted the query to another query of `Employees` or anything along those lines.

Comment: What happens if you put Distinct on the first query too?

Comment: The Distinct method uses object.Equals to determine if two objects are the same, and for all objects except anonymous types, Equals() returns false for different objects, even if all of their properties match (see value vs reference types). For anonymous types, the compiler overrides "Equals", and returns true if the values of all properties match. I don't see anything in your code that would cause duplicates, I would look for the problem elsewhere. Can you confirm that the duplicate doesn't exist before the second call?

Comment: I should clarify that for all _complex_ objects except for anonymous types...

Comment: Distinct did not solve the problem either, I tried that.  I even wrote a customer comparator class to use with Distinct, and the compiler was happy but I got a runtime error because LINQ to Entities could not support it.  Believe me, I spent the day trying everything before writing the hack I posted in my update...

Comment: Is there anything special about `Employees`'s primary key?

Comment: No, it's just two columns - PermanentClientID + EmployeeID, and must, of course, be unique.

Comment: Do you get duplicate results if you execute the SQL query?

Comment: I know that linq expressions and lambda expressions resolve to the same expressions behind the scenes, but for grins and giggles.  could you try changing the second part of the query to use this lambda expression if 

`(!string.IsNullorEmpty(divId))
   query = query.Where(emp.DivisionId == divId);` I'm interested if a similarly defined lambda expression will yield different results since you believe it's something with linq.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  The Employee entity actually points to a view, and I did not understand how the view was built.  The duplicates are supposed to be there, I just had to add one more column to the where clause.